# How to validate a parameter from another form in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, forms, validation, button, textbox

I have two forms, form1 and form2. I need to call a parameter of form1 from form2 in order validate that in form2.

This is the code in form1:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal parametro1 As Integer)

    InitializeComponent()
    TXB_MontoARetirar.Text = param1



End Sub

Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

This is the code in form2:

```
Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click

    Dim FRM As FRM_RetiroEfectivo2

    FRM = New FRM_RetiroEfectivo2()



    If FRM.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text = 100 Then

        FRM_RetireSuEfectivo1_100pesos.Show()
        Me.Hide()


    Else

        FRM_RetireSuEfectivo1.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End If

End Sub
```

When I run the program i get the following error:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string""to type 'Double' is not valid.'

Inner Exception
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Try: `If CInt(FRM.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text) = 100 Then` But you might have to perform other validation to assure that the user types in a number.

Comment: I tried that command but it didn't work. Now I get the following error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string""to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Inner Exception FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @JesusOvalles That's the part he was telling you about after the code: you'll want to validate that the user entered a number before you cast it.

Comment: Actually I have several forms, I wanted to explain it by giving an example of two forms to make it more understandable. The issue is that when I enter the value 100 in the textbox I get that error.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: One thing you will find out when you turn on Option Strict is that `FRM.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text = 100` cannot be true. `.Text` is a String and 100 is a number.

Comment: I fear you are having a problem between the default instance and the instanced you create of Forms. Here `FRM = New FRM_RetiroEfectivo2()` You create an instance of a form but you don't use it in the rest of the Sub. You do use a default instance of another form.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```vb
    If IsNumeric(FRM.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text) Then
         If CInt(FRM.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text) = 100 Then
            FRM_RetireSuEfectivo1_100pesos.Show()
            Me.Hide()
         End If
    Else
            FRM_RetireSuEfectivo1.Show()
            Me.Hide()         
    End If
```

Comment: When I try that command, it doesn't let me click on the PictureBox4.

Comment: @JesusOvalles If you add the statement `msgbox("'" & FRM.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text & "'")`  to the `Else` block, what _exactly_ do you see when you enter `100`? Seems there's something else going on.

Comment: @daShier It is preferable in .net to use a .TryParse instead of IsNumeric.

Comment: I am simulating an ATM. From a specific form (not from the form where I enter the number 100), I need to call several forms (not at the same time) with different types of bills (money). If I enter 100, I can call the bill form (money) of 100 and so on with others.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    If TXB_MontoARetirar.Text.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Debe llenar el campo.")
        Return
    End If
    If TXB_MontoARetirar.Text = "0" Then
        MsgBox("Introduzca el monto a retirar.")
        Return
    End If
    Dim intMonto As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TXB_MontoARetrirar.Text, intMonto) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the text box.")
        Return
    End If
    Select Case intMonto
        Case > 10000
            MsgBox("Solo es posible retirar hasta RD$10000.00 en los cajeros.")
            Return
        Case > 6000
            MsgBox("Fondos Insuficientes. Favor intentarlo otra vez.")
            Return
    End Select

    Dim NumMultiplo2 = intMonto Mod 100
    Dim NumMultiplo3 = intMonto Mod 200
    Dim NumMultiplo4 = intMonto Mod 500
    Dim NumMultiplo5 = intMonto Mod 1000
    Dim NumMultiplo6 = intMonto Mod 2000
    If NumMultiplo2 = 0 OrElse NumMultiplo3 = 0 OrElse NumMultiplo4 = 0 OrElse NumMultiplo5 = 0 OrElse NumMultiplo6 = 0 Then
        Dim Respuesta = MessageBox.Show("Desea imprimir un recibo?", "Imprimir Recibo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If Respuesta = DialogResult.Yes Then
            FRM_RetireSuTarjeta.Show()
        Else
            FRM_RetireSuTarjeta1.Show()
        End If
        TXB_MontoARetirar.Text = ""
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("Solo se pueden realizar retiros en multiplos de billetes de RD$100.00, RD$200.00, RD$500.00, RD$1000.00 y RD$2000.00 pesos.")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have no idea what this code is doing but perhaps, seeing it simplified will help you see where it is going wrong. Those nested If statements got way out of hand. When you are writing the same code over and over, make a Sub or Function. In this case I just combined it all to a single IF.

Comment: I am simulating an ATM. From a specific form (not from the form where I enter the number 100), I need to call several forms (not at the same time) with different types of bills (money). If I enter 100, I can call the bill form (money) of 100 and so on with others.